# Listener does not connect to the correct instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, listener

I have an instance with Always ON and two replicas, one of primary and one of secondary. I have created another instance and enabled Always On, each group located in different instances has a different listener with IP and different port. For the first case the listener works well, that is, it connects to the primary replica, and when the failover is done it behaves well. For the case of the second listener, I do not know why to try to connect through this, I am connecting to the group-instance of the first listener, someone has any ideas ??. For the second case, the replicas are fine, synchronized, the problem is that the listener does not connect where it should.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By default a standalone SQL Server instance (ie non Failover Cluster Instance), will listen on its port on All IP Addresses.  See  [TCP/IP Properties (IP Addresses Tab)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/tcp-ip-properties-ip-addresses-tab?view=sql-server-2017).

And this means that the instance will accept TCP connections on its designated port on all current and future IP addresses.  So when the Cluster brings the AG Listener IP address online, it won't just be the SQL Instance that owns the AG that listens on that IP address.